# Uh ... 0 featured questions ...?

Tags: bug

This can't be right. On the main TeX.SX, it says that there are "0" featured questions ... ?

Yet, I count seven (one is missing from my screenshot).

[image]

It's still saying "0" even after a hard refresh ... Not sure what's going on ...

My browser is Firefox 26.0 if that is potentially relevant. I've always accessed TeX.SX via Firefox, and I've never seen this behavior before.

---

**Update 1**: Now, when I go to https://tex.stackexchange.com/ it says "7" (though it didn't before), but when I click on "featured" (that is, when I go to https://tex.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) it still says "0".

**Update 2**: Just kidding, the behavior mentioned in Update 1 is now gone. https://tex.stackexchange.com/ is back to saying "0", not "7".

---

**Update 3**: After a few hours of vacillating between the original noted behavior and the behavior noted in Update 1, it seems as if things have gone back to normal for me ... Perhaps this question should be closed in a day, or so, assuming I don't see the behavior resurface? I'm not sure. Did anyone else notice this happening for them?

Comment: about the same time as you originally asked the question, i encountered a momentary glitch, switching back from meta to the main tex.sx site -- 0 questions reported.  obviously that was bogus, so i clicked on "questions" and got a respectable response.  some other pexuliar things have been happening today, but everything seems back to normal now.

Comment: please follow up on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215792/heisenbug-alert-featured-tab-is-sometimes-borked)